# class loading of OSGi on Required-Bundle and Imported-Package

Tags: osgi, classloader

For OSGi bundle, we can add dependencies by using Required-Bundle or Imported-Package. Now I have below case:

Both bundle A and bundle B export same packages, but bundle B with higher version, like:

```
bundle A:
   Exported Packages:
     xxx.a,
     xxx.b,
     xxx.c

bundle B:
   Exported Packages:
     xxx.a; version="5.0.0",
     xxx.b; version="5.0.0",
     xxx.c; version="5.0.0"
```

And bundle C has the dependency to package a, b, c, so it adds A in its Required-Bundle list, like

```
bundle C:
     Required Bundles:
       A
```

Let's assume both bundle A and B are resolved in the framework. So when resolving bundle C, which packages/classes are been loaded by C, the classes in A or classes B? I think is A. Am i right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the packages from A are used because you require bundle A.

Please note that Require-Bundle is [considered deprecated](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Use_Import-Package_instead_of_Require-Bundle) by most OSGi developers.

Comment: thanks, i'm try to understand the bundle resolving of OSGi and want to confirm...-_-

Comment: Well, OSGi is not trying to trick you. If you ask for A, you get A.

Comment: Technically C does not load the classes, they are loaded by A which holds them. But the Require-Bundle statement makes the classes loaded by A visible to C.

Comment: Hi @NeilBartlett, where is the link target moved to?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't perform this move. Maybe @BJHargrave knows.

Comment: The wiki.osgi.org site became infected with malware and it was shut down.